# rake aborted! no such file to load -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I run a rake task every night via cron (as root), when it runs it gives the error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
```

which I get in an email

When I run it manually (as root), it runs just fine.

I am running rvm if that helps.

I am not really sure what to add to help, but here are a few things.

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]

# rails -v
Rails 3.0.9

# gem -v
1.8.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set up your cron task like this

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'rake blah:blah'
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thank you

Comment: so I ran what you said, and today I got this:  stdin: is not a tty
rake aborted!
Could not find acts_as_audited_rails3-1.1.2 in any of the sources  I did not have that gem installed globally, so I have installed that this morning and now have to wait till tomorrow to see what happens.

Comment: You can just create some test empty rake task and set cron to execute it in 10 min, so you don't have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: this got me to the right place.  Since I am using RVM and I don't seem to have it setup correctly on my server, I had to use that command to install rails and to do bundle install then it worked.  Thank you for the point in the right direction